# Is there a correlation between social justice awareness and "social inclusivity"?

Tags: social-psychology, political-psychology

I am curious to what extent social justice awareness translates to a personal level.

"Social justice awareness" is a basic understanding of the challenges faced by various minorities (race, religion, gender, sexual orientation, low SES, physically disabled, neurodivergent, etc).

"Social inclusiveness" is a *personal* trait. I use this term to indicate that a person is more open to accepting a wider range of people into their own social circle. One would *think* it goes hand-in-hand with social-justice aware viewpoints, as per these examples:

- Forgiveness aspect:

  - S. Justice: "Ban the box" and other felon re-enfranchisement mechanisms. Better safety nets.
  - Personal: Less likely to ghost a new friend if they refuse to pay for a meal, cancel a meetup, etc.
- Diversity aspect:

  - S. Justice: Easing immigration laws. Better multilingual resources. Not stereotyping groups of people.
  - Personal: Curiosity with regard to unusual ideas or unfamiliar conversation topics. Not stereotyping individuals. Able to hold productive debates with people from with opposing viewpoints.
- "Soft-boundary" aspect:

  - S. Justice: Favoring civil/community approaches over criminal enforcement for drug offenses.
  - Personal: Finding ways to set boundaries that don't make the other party feel bad. Such as limiting total interaction time but still responding to messages within the day.
- "Favoring the underdog" aspect:

  - S. Justice: Voting to naturalize undocumented immigrants.
  - Personal: Following content creators with less than a hundred followers.

However, I can't tell if there is a relationship between one's personal behaviors and how much they seem to be aware of (or care about) social justice. Is there a reasonable correlation here?

Comment: Welcome Quantum P. Could you clarify how any of this might fit into existing models of psychology or neuroscience. What you've accumulated here seems to be a great many buzz-words and standard phrases from a certain type of you-tube video, but it's unclear how it relates to what we do here. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [ask] section of the [help], then edit to tell us which standard models you're referencing and to show your own research into the question as asked.

Comment: I'd point you towards perhaps looking into personality trait: [openness](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC10461810/) for a starter on the topic, then finding out about any correlates. Emotional and cognitive empathy might be worth looking into as well. Not certain that I've ever seen any metric for awareness of social justice as you describe it - excepting perhaps among those who's job it is to work in a care setting as a necessary prerequisite (and present in varying degrees, but learnable).

Comment: @JiminyCricket: I am not sure what you mean by "great many buzz-words" given that I provide concrete examples of each of the two traits I am talking about. Is there a way to rephrase some of the sentences to be less "buzz-wordy"?

Comment: The traits you're talking about aren't recognized categories in psychology (as far as I know, please advise otherwise if I'm off-track). What I mean is that much of what you're asking seems to me to be more suited to a political/sociology site than a psychology and neuroscience one.  There is a crossover, sure, but could you relate this to recognized models within this site's remit.

Comment: @JiminyCricket: That makes sense. Should I delete it and repost it on Politics.SE (is there a Sociology.SE?) instead?

Comment: I'm not frequently on [politics.se], but check it out, be sure to take their tour and read-up in their help centre about how to ask and what's on-topic *before* posting. There isn't a sociology stack (yet). If you want to propose a new site (say, sociology) then see [this main-meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) post for details.

Comment: I agree this question is walking a thin line, but appreciated the clarity (other than the unclear use of "political" to refer back to "social justice awareness"). I think the question should be interpreted as a request to find related/relevant terminology within the scope of this site, which in related studies may or may not have a direct answer to this question. Hence, a reference to "openness" and similar concepts may very well be the start of an appropriate answer!

Comment: @StevenJeuris: Replaced "Political" with "S Justice".